スタンドアロンのGASでスプレッドシート特定セルの編集を検知し、ページを自動で強制的に更新したい
ウェブページに特定セル（以下A1とします）に入力されている文字を表示し続けたいです。
ページは二つあり、URLにアクセスしたら表示されるホームページと、そこからアクセスできるセル表示ページです。
セル表示ページにアクセスした瞬間の文字は取得して表示することができるのですが、A1が編集されたら表示する文字を更新するという機能をどう実現したらいいのかわかりません。
onEditでスプレッドシートの編集を検知することはできました。
以下コード.gs内のセル表示ページにアクセスする部分です
const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("cellHyouji");
        template.cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getDisplayValue();
        const htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
        return htmlOutput

htmlは次のようなっています。
<p><?= cell ?></p>


web ページ側は、何で書かれていますか？PHP ですか？

GASなのでjavaです

Google App Script は JavaScript に似た言語ですが、Java とは別物のはずです。


スプレッドシート特定セルの編集を検知し、ページを自動で強制的に更新したい

スタンドアロンの Google App Script では、サーバー(*.gs) から、HTML(クライアント) への通信はできないようです。
クライアントからサーバーのスクリプト呼び出しはできるようです。

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

よって、サーバー側で検知したイベントをトリガーにして、クライアント側に通知を送ることはできないと思われます。
クライアント側で、一定時間間隔で、サーバー側のスクリプトを呼び出し、変更があれば、更新するといった実装であればできると思います。
